# What is the difference between generic and specific scaffolding?

Tags: automated-testing, test-management, application-software-testing

I searched the difference on google. But could'nt find any intuitive explanation for both the terms. Can someone give me the main differences between the two in software testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [**Wikipedia**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scaffold_(programming)):
>   Scaffolding is a project generation technique supported by various tools.

In your examples, I don't believe the term 'scaffolding' refers to two different things, but instead is being used as a spectrum.

The difference is between the adjectives [generic](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/generic) and [specific](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/specific). `Specific` is something clearly defined or identified, whereas `generic` applies to a group of things and is the exact opposite of 'specific'.

So, in testing terms, does the scaffolding serve a generic purpose or a more specific one?

Further reading:

- [Test Execution. Mauro Pezzè & Michal Young, 2007](https://ix.cs.uoregon.edu/~michal/book/slides/pdf/PezzeYoung-Ch17-execution.pdf).
- [Software Testing (s7.9 and s7.10). Author unknown, 2013](https://elearningatria.files.wordpress.com/2013/10/unit7-sgc.pdf).
- [What's the difference between generic and specific? Ronan, 2014](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/167227/283087)

Comment: Can you give some more points of difference?

Comment: Hi @HimanshuPoddar, I've added some further reading which you might find interesting or helpful.